laravel cashier stripe webhook not working in localhost with stripe cli
so basically when i try to connect Laravel with stripe with the command run php artisan cashier:webhook. First i run stripe login then i run php artisan cashier:webhook
after running this command  a error is popup saying - URL must be publicly accessible consider using stripe cli for test webhook locally . But i am already in stripe cli . anyone know how can i solve this issue and how can i test stripe webhook locally.
 Invalid URL: URL must be publicly accessible. Consider using a tool like the Stripe CLI to test webhooks locally: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli

What is the command that you used to run the Stripe CLI webhook listener?

"By default, the created webhook will point to the URL defined by the APP_URL environment variable and the cashier.webhook route that is included with Cashier. You may provide the --url option when invoking the command if you would like to use a different URL". Have you defined the correct URL? Documentation reference

i just go to my project directory and run stripe login then after login i try to run cashier:webhook . And my web url is fine just http://localhost . but after run cashier:webhook there is a error showing that my url is not publicly accessable and i should use stripe cli. but i am already using stripe cli .

Please help me with the same issue

Go to the .env file and search for APP_URL=http://localhost, and replace localhost with stripe.test:
 APP_URL=http://stripe.test

This will allow you to run php artisan cashier:webhook.

stripe login
    Your pairing code is: enjoy-enough-outwit-win
This pairing code verifies your authentication with Stripe.
Press Enter to open the browser or visit https://dashboard.stripe.com/stripecli/confirm_auth?t=THQdJfL3x12udFkNorJL8OF1iFlN8Az1 (^C to quit)

Then just change 8000 to which ever port your using
stripe listen --forward-to localhost:8000/stripe/webhook --skip-verify


I had this issue and solved it by not using localhost:8000, but a custom local domain. For those that are hitting issues with "php artisan cashier:webhook", make sure you are not using localhost:8000. Install "laravel valet" through composer to use a custom local domain. Add that domain to your APP_URL and the command will then work.
Laravel Valet: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/valet
For Mac OS X users:
Install using composer
composer global require laravel/valet

Install valet from the composer folder in your user directory
~/.composer/vendor/bin/valet install

Navigate to the root folder of your Laravel project and valet park the directory (add it to valet):
valet park

then create the custom domain using Valet Link
valet link nameofyourdomain

you will now have a custom domain http://nameofyourdomain.test that you can use to access your Laravel installation.


Go to your Stripe test environment > Developers > Webhooks.
Click on Add a local listener



Follow the instructions as shown below. Run stripe login and stripe listen --forward-to your_local_webhook_url



Open a new tab and trigger stripe events with stripe trigger the_event

